# Should we edit part of the tour?

Tags: discussion

In chat, [jimsug wrote](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22280807#22280807),

> The tour page encourages practical questions users have actually faced. I suppose we will have to change this to ... conform to our preference for questions that do not seek legal advice?

This is a problem, as, by default, [the tour](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour) says,

> Ask about...
>
> - Specific issues with law
> - Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered

Should we change this, and, if so, what should we change it to?

Comment: Yes!  Should we digest the contents of http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/q/10/10 for the tour?

Comment: @feetwet That's a good idea.

Comment: I'm still open to making a change here, but I need wording from the community because (among other reasons) I don't know enough to come up with it myself. cc @feetwet