# Edits to opening paragraph(s) of the tour (July 2015)

Tags: discussion

[Currently the opening paragraph for the tour reads](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour):

> **Law Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for legal professionals, students, and others with experience or interest in law. It's built and run *by you* as part of the [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about law.

The moderation team is considering an edit to this to change it to:

> **Law Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for legal professionals, students, and others with experience or interest in law. It's built and run *by you* as part of the [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about law. The answers you get here are not a substitute for legal advice, and the users here aren't acting as your lawyer.

We would like to open discussion on this issue for community input. The change is designed to address concerns about Unauthorized Practice of Law (UPL) issues and provide some notice that while this can be a useful place to learn about the law, that it is not a substitute for legal advice.

See also:

- [Should we edit part of the tour?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142/should-we-edit-part-of-the-tour)

Comment: Note that we don't really have any stats on how often the Tour page is viewed, so there's no guarantee that this will catch all or even most users at some point. There is [a shiny bronze badge](http://law.stackexchange.com/help/badges/84/informed) for reading it, though! (Which is probably the closest we'll get to view stats on it.) **Also** I would venture that this wouldn't address all concerns about UPL/malpractice but it's a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that there have been upvotes to the question, but no alternative suggestions I'll go ahead and make the edit. I did make one slight change from "users" to "other contributors".